# filesystem read only

Tags: filesystems, opensuse

My filesystem is read-only for several days.
Searching for somesthing on my `/var/log/messages` and found this.

```
****EMITTING CHANGED for /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda
****Refreshing ATA SMART data for /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda
helper(pid 3495):launched job udisks-helper-ata-smart-collect on /dev/sda
helper(pid 3495):completed with exit code 0
```

I this a health test:

```
# smartctl -d ata -H /dev/sda
```

and get the follow output:

```
smartctl 5.42 2011-10-20 r3458 [x86_64-linux-3.1.0-1.2-default] (SUSE RPM)
Copyright (C) 2002-11 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
```

what can I do to prevent my filesystem to get readonly?

Comment: Ok it looks like my filesystem is useless... will try to find a solution but if somebody have something to say, any idea it could be nice!

Comment: Check `dmesg` (run that) to see if anything is there.

Comment: Also, please tell us *which* filesystem, and also post its /etc/fstab entry.

Comment: Made a mistake with badblocks... will continue it later =D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could still be a file system of disk failure.  Take a look at dmesg for more clues.  If you have rebooted - does it come up clean or does it warn you about filesystem problems?

You should be able to remount the file system read-write using:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

However, it would be a good idea to try to figure out what exactly caused it to mount read-only first.

It is possible to hit a keyboard shortcut that would remount the root filesystem read-only.  Usually its **Alt + SysRq + U**.

Comment: I know that but `mount -o remount,rw /` doesn't do anything.

Comment: my disk was broken after all forgot to grant an answer thanks...

Answer (score 4):

Run a file system check (AKA "check disk") on the disk `fsck /dev/sda`. If the disk check report unrepairable sections, that could be why the system is mounting the disk read only. If the disk can be repaired, boot with a Live CD or Rescue Disk for your system and un `fsck -f` on the disk to repair it.

Comment: Ok `fsck.reiserfs -f /dev/sda` gave me this output `the reiserfs superblock cannot be found on /dev/sda. Failed to open the filesystem.`

Comment: @Tim: No, he wants to fsck the partition, not the whole disk. So /dev/sda1 or whatever.

Comment: but also, you're having him run a fsck *on a mounted partition*. Generally not the best of ideas...

Comment: @Solo: So it's reiserfs? Migrate to another fs.

Comment: @derobert I'm have not run a fsck on a mounted partition; I'm used a liveCD to do that.

Comment: @derobert very last line of my post: "boot with a Live CD or Rescue Disk for your system and un fsck -f on the disk to repair it." Seems clear to me, did you miss it?

Comment: @Tim I'm talking about the first line of the post. At minimum (for e2fsck) you need to add `-n` (and I seem to recall previous versions having bugs around that). For reiserfs, I'm not sure. Keep in mind the fsck will often attempt a journal replay.